# adb.exe wont start from intelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, adb, android-virtual-device

I have the latests intelliJ ultimate installed.

I managed to install android sdk and was working fine with the emulator.

For various reasons I had to restart my PC. Now when I start intelliJ I get the following error message

```
ADB not responding. You can wait more, or kill "adb.exe" process manually and click 'Restart'
Errors from ADB:
adb: Unexpected exception 'Cannot run program "C:\Programs\Android \SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied' while attempting to get adb version from 'C:\Programs\Android\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe'
```

Ive tried 
* deleting my .android folder in c:/users/{username}
* restarting my pc and intelliJ again
* turning off my firewall

I can seem to start it if I do

```
adb.exe start-server
```

Although if i do this and then start intelliJ then intelliJ says it cannot communicate with adb.exe and  asks if I want to

- wait (if I do this nothign happens)
- restart (same error as above)
- cancel (means I have no adb so i cannot start the emulator)

Any ideas? Im really frustrated because I was really loving the android development but now are stuck at the first hurdle again

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by removed the .intelliJ directory in c:\users\{username} and then starting intelliJ again.

This can be a bit time consuming so now I do the following steps

- open IntelliJ and set up all my config
- take a backup of .intelliJ directory
- code away :)
- if/when I get this error again I then delete my c:\users....intelliJ directory and copy the backup over

I can lose some config but not everything that I might have set up (eg sdks setups etc)

Answer (score 2):

`adb` runs on port 5037, and you can use `cmd` (Command Prompt) to do the following:

```
C:\>netstat -aon|findstr "5037"
TCP 127.0.0.1:5037 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 2048
TCP 127.0.0.1:5037 127.0.0.1:49435 ESTABLISHED 2048
TCP 127.0.0.1:49435 127.0.0.1:5037 ESTABLISHED 6472
```

To kill the process,

```
taskkill /pid 2048 /f
```

Other method to kill the process:

1. Using the PID

   Format: `ntsd -c q -p pid`

   Example: `ntsd -c q -p 1332` (Ends `explorer.exe`)
2. Using the process name

   Format: `ntsd -c q -pn ***.exe` (`***.exe` is the name of the process)

   Example: `ntsd -c q -pn explorer.exe`